# Yii, Fancybox and ajax-loaded data

Tags: ajax, validation, yii, fancybox

I have a link that looks like

```
<a class="fancy" href="/site/feedback">feedback</a>
```

Ajax call:

```
$('.fancy').fancybox({
    wrapCSS: 'custom-fancy',
    padding: 0,
    type: 'ajax'
});
```

On click fancybox load content wich controller send.

```
$this->renderPartial('_feedback')
```

Feedback view:

```
<?php
/* @var $this Controller */
/* @var $model FeedbackForm */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */

$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'feedback-form',
    'enableClientValidation' => TRUE,
)); ?>
<div><?= $form->textArea($model, 'feedback') ?></div>
<?=$form->error($model, 'feedback')?>
<? $this->widget('CCaptcha') ?>
<?=$form->textField($model, 'verifyCode', array('placeholder' => 'Captcha code'))?>
<div><?=CHtml::submitButton('Send', array('class' => 'r button'))?></div>
<? $this->endWidget() ?>
```

The problem is that there is no javascript/ajax validation on this loaded form. I think, it is because some Yii scripts did not loaded after ajax call (yiiActiveForm.js maybe, I don't know).
What is the best solution for this situation?

Comment: Please show your ajax code where you are load feedback form

Comment: added to post, but it's to simple, fancybox doing my work himself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you  need to load some code with javascript

```
$output = $this->renderPartial('_feedback', array(), true)
// you need set layout to false for render only your form
Yii::app()->clientScript->render($output);
// where you need remove jquery for prevent double initiation's jquery script
// it's not worked example!!!
preg_replace('@<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>@mi', '', $output);
// well, we may output
echo $output;
```

Comment: I doing it in controller, but server send me only html of my form, without any js.

Answer (score 4):

We need to set **$processOutput** is **true** as a fourth parameter. (***RenderPartial postprocess default value is false***.) Then only **$processOutput** method will insert registered client scripts into the output at appropriate places.

```
$this->renderPartial('view file', array(data to be available to view file), false, true);
```